# Is there a way to pipe the output of one AWS CLI command as the input to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm attempting to call run-instances and pass the resulting instance IDs as the input to create-tags as a one-liner as follows:

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
    --image-id ami-1234 \
    --output text \
    --query Instances[*].InstanceId | \
aws ec2 create-tags \
    --tags 'Key="foo",Value="bar"'
```

When attempting this, I get the following:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --resources is required
```

Is something like this possible or does one have to resort to using variables (or some other way I'm not thinking about)?

**Additional Background**

The motivation for asking this question is that something like this is possible with the AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell; I was hoping to accomplish the same thing with the AWS CLI.

Equivalent PowerShell example:

```
New-EC2Instance -ImageId ami-1234 |
    ForEach-Object Instances |
    ForEach-Object InstanceId |
    New-EC2Tag -Tag @{key='foo';value='bar'}
```

Comment: You'll need to write a script to capture the output from the first command and feed it to the second command as parameters. There is no way the pipe you are using would work, how would it know what to make of the text being piped into it?

Comment: That's what I suspected, I just wanted to be sure. FWIW something like this is possible with the AWS PowerShell tools (commands declare a "value from pipeline" attribute), but that's more of a function of PowerShell rather than the AWS commands.

Comment: @MarkB `create-tags` takes a `resources` parameter which is the instance Id (can be a list, but in this case it will be single value) to tag which is the Id of the instance you just launched and given from the query result of the `run-instnace` command. am I missing something ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri no you aren't missing anything. However nothing you just said indicates you can pipe the output like what is shown in the original question. You have to capture it somehow using scripting or something. In your answer you are capturing it and passing it as a parameter using `xargs`.

Comment: @MarkB I capture more with {} so I can pass it to resources param rightt but thats how pipe works in command Line shell

Comment: While Frederic's answer is the good one to your question, if what you really want is PowerShell style commands, then take a look at https://bash-my-aws.org   It may not be as good as PowerShell, but at least is better than having to use xargs.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It can be done by leveraging `xargs -I` to capture the instance IDs to feed it into the --resources parameter of create-tags.

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
    --image-id ami-1234 \
    --output text \
    --query Instances[*].[InstanceId] | \
xargs -I {} aws ec2 create-tags \
    --resources {} \
    --tags 'Key="foo",Value="bar"'
```

Note that unlike the example in the original question, it's important to wrap the "InstanceId" portion of the --query parameter value in brackets so that if one calls run-instances with --count greater than one, the multiple instance IDs that get returned will be outputted as separate lines instead of being tab-delimited. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#controlling-output-format

Comment: Sincere thanks for the shell lesson; I'm afraid I showed my Linux ignorance on this one. This worked great so long as I'm spinning up one instance at a time (which in fairness satisfies my question); I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to work when --count is greater than 1 (again, showing my Linux ignorance). If you have the time/inclination, could you update the answer to account for multiple instances?

Comment: FWIW, the reason multiple instances wasn't working has to do with the --query parameter value: in my example it return the multiple instance IDs tab-delimited. Wrapping "InstanceId" in brackets within the --query parameter value solves the issue. I'll update the answer. Thanks for your help @Frédéric

Comment: Thanks Rafael - I updated the answer based on your proposal as I saw it was rejected but think it makes full sense

Comment: Also adding `-t` to the `xargs` command will allow you to see the command that will be executing.