# How to use output from one AWS CLI command as input to other

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

I am running an AWS CLI command to get the latest Auto-scaling Group name in a given account, now I want to use the output (i.e. ASG Name) as an input to other AWS command to update that ASG.
Command to get the ASG name:

`aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "sort_by(AutoScalingGroups,&CreatedTime)[-1].{id:AutoScalingGroupName}" --output text`

Command to update the ASG returned by above command:

`aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name $NameReturnedByAboveCommand`

I tried these solutions but I am not able to get it to work:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38153936/2858235
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#controlling-output-format

I am using windows command but also tried using PS but no luck.

Comment: `$NameReturnedByAboveCommand = aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups ...`. Depending on what the output actually looks like you may need to parse it to get it into a form suitable for passing it to the next command.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I am running it on windows command prompt and I tried this but it says `'$Output' is not recognized as an internal or external command`:   `$O=aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "sort_by(AutoScalingGroups,&CreatedTime)[-1].{id:AutoScalingGroupName}" --output text echo O=$O aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --health-check-grace-period 12 --auto-scaling-group-name "$O"`

Comment: my output is just a text, i.e. name of the auto-scaling group

Comment: If you're running it from the Command Prompt then why is your question tagged "powershell"? Also, please [edit] your question if you need to provide additional information. You've been a member for almost 6 years. Why do I need to tell you this?

Comment: I am actually using both for testing :) So when I ran the same command in PS it says `Unknown options: O=, aws, autoscaling`

Comment: I am going to mark is as answer if you want to put it in the answers.

Comment: I don't think something as trivial as assgning command output to a variable would warrant an answer.